# Как вывести данные из БД в smarty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, smarty

как вывести данные из БД в smarty? Я делал так:
index.php

https://pastebin.com/cXbMR4Ng

index.tpl:

https://pastebin.com/G5DhydpU

но смарти выдаёт ошибку:
Notice: Undefined index: rw in C:\web\templates_c\d376f5d67a0ec32ce4f73820d1aba109b1d04078_ 0.file.index.tpl.php on line 32

Notice: Trying to get property 'value' of non-object in C:\web\templates_c\d376f5d67a0ec32ce4f73820d1aba109b1d04078_ 0.file.index.tpl.php on line 32
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас древний смарти второй версии что ли?

метод [`assign()`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/api.assign.tpl) принимает либо два аргумента - имя и значение, либо ассоциативный массив. а не просто кучу аргументов, как у вас.

передаете целиком весь массив данных в шаблон

```
$st = $db->query("select field1, field2...");  // не надо использовать звездочку
$data = $st->fetchAll('assoc');                // получите сразу весь массив

$smarty->assign('data', $data);
$smarty->assign('title', "main page");
```

в шаблоне пишите цикл по массиву

```
<ul>
{foreach $data as $d}
    <li>{$data.name} ....</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: На это php выдаёт ошибку: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool

Comment: @elePHPant вы уж отредактируйте код под свои потребности. первые две строки - примерные. Суть в том, чтоыб перечислить поля запроса, выбрать все данные разом, и получить их в виде ассоциативного массива. Я не знаю, какой именно механизм работы с БД вы используете.  (зы: судя по тексту у вас в SQL запросе ошибка)

Comment: я исправил sql-запрос. Теперь:  PDOStatement::fetchAll() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given

Comment: "отредактируйте под свои потребности" обозначает осмыслисть идею и пойти почитать как это делается в вашем случае. С учетом того, что у вас PDO, то в качестве параметра передать `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: Спасибо! Я разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог пользователь @teran. Я сделал так:

index.php:

https://pastebin.com/WBpeEQsG

index.tpl

https://pastebin.com/ZW1arwDb

и всё заработало.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]